# How to update the JSON object without deleting old values using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "request_id": "8123",
    "lease_id": "",
    "renewable": false,
    "lease_duration": 4576,
    "data": {
        "mynew": "123",
        "name": "sample"
    },
    "wrap_info": null,
    "warnings": null,
    "auth": null
}
```

I'm tring to add new values under data, after adding new values it should look this way:

```
{
    "request_id": "8123",
    "lease_id": "",
    "renewable": false,
    "lease_duration": 4576,
    "data": {
        "mynew": "123",
        "name": "sample"
    },
    {
        "mynew": "xyz",
        "name": "newsample"
    },
    "wrap_info": null,
    "warnings": null,
    "auth": null
}
```

Comment: I'm tring to add new values under data, after adding new values it should look this way:{ "request_id": "8123", "lease_id": "", "renewable": false, "lease_duration": 4576, "data": { "mynew": "123", "name": "sample" },{"mynew":"xyz","name":"newsample"} ,"wrap_info": null, "warnings": null, "auth": null }

Comment: Please provide more information ... as i see data is an object you can add new field in data like data.newfield = value ... but you cannot add new object to data unless you make data as array of object.

Comment: @patrick please add any relevant information to the question. I have added your comment because your expected output is very hard to read inline.

Comment: `"data": {
        "mynew": "123",
        "name": "sample"
    },
    {
        "mynew": "xyz",
        "name": "newsample"
    },` is not valid JSON. `data` would have to be an _array_ in order to do what you want e.g. `"data": [{
        "mynew": "123",
        "name": "sample"
    },
    {
        "mynew": "xyz",
        "name": "newsample"
    }],`

Answer (score 3):

Your `data` property should be of array type so that you can add multiple objects with same object structure like:

```
var obj = {
    "request_id": "8123",
    "lease_id": "",
    "renewable": false,
    "lease_duration": 4576,
    "data": [{
      "mynew": "123",
      "name": "sample"
    }, {
      "mynew": "xyz",
      "name": "newsample"
    }],
    "wrap_info": null,
    "warnings": null,
    "auth": null
};
```

Then you can easily add a new object by pushing it to the `data` array:

```js
var obj = {
  "request_id": "8123",
  "lease_id": "",
  "renewable": false,
  "lease_duration": 4576,
  "data": [{
    "mynew": "123",
    "name": "sample"
  }],
  "wrap_info": null,
  "warnings": null,
  "auth": null
};
var newData = {
  "mynew": "xyz",
  "name": "newsample"
};
obj.data.push(newData);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

try formatting you json as

```
var json = { "request_id": "8123", "lease_id": "", "renewable": false, "lease_duration": 4576, "data": [{ "mynew": "123", "name": "sample" }], "wrap_info": null, "warnings": null, "auth": null }
```

make data as an array and then you can just do `json.data.push(newObject);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use Object.assign(target, newsource) to add new values to the target object without loosing your previous data. it will just update the particular value. 
eg.

```
const obj = {name: 'xyz', email: 'abc@yahoo.com'}
const newobj = Object.assign({obj, {email:'xyz@yahoo.com'})
console.log(newobj)
{name: 'xyz', email:'xyz@yahoo.com'}
```

for JSON data you can use JSON.parse to convert it to object and the when you are done, just use

```
JSON.stringfy(newobj)
```